# How list elements horizonatlly with nested lists?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to improve myself at web development. I've been trying to design web product landing page, and i'm stuck at pricing section. I've tried solutions that i've found at internet(like w3schools etc.) Couldn't work out what to do. So here's question:

I've a div like that and every member of class 'productsli' is my products, trying to design a card for my visitor. And i want to show them horizontally but i couldn't. Here's my css code for them:

```css
#products{
  grid-area:3/2/4/3;
  display:grid;
  margin-top:200px;
  
}
#products ul{
  list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
}
#products li{
  list-style-type:none;

}
```

```html
  <div id="products">
    <ul>
      <li  class="prodcustli">
        <ul>
          <li><h3>Razer kulaklık</h3></li>
          <li><p>lorem ipsum dolor</p></li>
        </ul>  
      </li>
        <li  class="prodcustli">
        <ul>
          <li><h3>Razer kulaklık</h3></li>
          <li><p>lorem ipsum dolor</p></li>
        </ul>  
      </li>
        <li  class="prodcustli">
        <ul>
          <li><h3>Razer kulaklık</h3></li>
          <li><p>lorem ipsum dolor</p></li>
        </ul>  
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

What should i do?

Comment: Please be more specific on your problem or what you want to achieve because your lists already displaying horizontally

Comment: @YalcinKilic In code snippet yes it seems like displaying horizontally but in codepen it won't seem horizontally. Can i send a link in stackoverflow? Is it allowed?

Comment: You can put the link in the comments section

Comment: https://codepen.io/ddennis/pen/zYoZOoW here's my codepen link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your codepen example, your wrapper with the id #products has not enough width. Give it a width-value and your problem should be solved

Answer (score 1):

Hello Your Div Containing The Lists Doesnot Have enough width to Keep the sub divisions in the same line. So you can do this:

```css
#header{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  background-color:#004dc9;
  justify-content:space-between;
  position:fixed;
  align-items:center;
  grid-area:header;
}
#header-img{
  height:100%;
}
.nav-link{
  float:left;
  font-size:42px;
  padding-right:35px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
}
body{
  display:grid;
  justify-items:center;
  background-color:#FFFDD0;
  grid-template-columns:33% 50% 33%;
  grid-template-rows: 33% 33% 33%;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "advert content content"
    "footer footer footer"
}
@media(max-width:300px){
  body{
    grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "content content advert"
    "footer footer footer"
  }
}
#video{
  grid-area:2/2/3/3;
}
#form{
  grid-area:3/2/4/3;
  margin-top:150px;
}
#products{
  grid-area:3/2/4/3;
  display:grid;
  margin-top:200px;
  width: 100%;
  
}
#products ul{
  list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
}
#products li{
  list-style-type:none;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <img id="header-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Free_logo.svg/1280px-Free_logo.svg.png">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#video">link1</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#video">link2</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#video">link3</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LIvSF0fQPJc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe><br>
  <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your E-Mail" required>
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
  </form>
  <div id="products">
    <ul>
      <li  class="prodcustli">
        <ul>
          <li><h3>Razer kulaklık</h3></li>
          <li><p>lorem ipsum dolor</p></li>
        </ul>  
      </li>
        <li  class="prodcustli">
        <ul>
          <li><h3>Razer kulaklık</h3></li>
          <li><p>lorem ipsum dolor</p></li>
        </ul>  
      </li>
        <li  class="prodcustli">
        <ul>
          <li><h3>Razer kulaklık</h3></li>
          <li><p>lorem ipsum dolor</p></li>
        </ul>  
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Also You Must Link The Javascript At The End Of The Body Statement